# How to override/change lay-out of Ruby on Rails spree app after installing Bootstrap gem?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, deface

I have a Spree Commerce application with the spree_bootstrap gem installed by adding

```
gem 'spree_bootstrap', github: 'jdutil/spree_bootstrap'
```

to the Gemfile.

Now on the main page I have all the familiar bootstrap divs as `<div class="container row">` and `<ul id="main-nav-bar" class="inline">`.

I am new to Rails and I want to change the lay-out masterpage by adding my own custom navbar and other tweaks. Unfortunately application.html.rb is a virtually empty page and I don't think that is the one to make changes.

My question is: how do I override or change the standard div values? I do not have the files locally. I've heard about using Deface as a tool, but I don't know how to use it.

I hope someone here can provide some more insight on changing the standard bootstrap Spree application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the file `app/views/spree/layouts/spree_application.html.erb`. Copy and paste [this](https://github.com/jdutil/spree_bootstrap/blob/master/app/views/spree/layouts/spree_application.html.erb) content then edit as you wish :)

Repeat for any other Spree views and partials that you might want to restyle. If you'd like to know the paths you need to create & the content for a certain view or partial, check out the `app/views/spree` folder of their [GitHub repo](https://github.com/jdutil/spree_bootstrap/tree/master/app/views/spree).

You might need to restart your server before seeing any changes.

Comment: Great. Now I realize the rumors were true: all pages are taken from git and only if you want to change them you have to add them locally. Thanks!

Comment: Question: right now I get an error in `app/views/spree/products/_image.html.erb`. I want to change the code there so locally I added a file with the same path and name with the desired new code. Then I deployed it and when I ssh into the server I see the file. But on the website I still get the same error. Since trace of template inclusion said it came from `app/views/spree/products/show.html.erb` I also changed that file to it, but I still see the same code on the server. How do I fix this?

Comment: Any gem / engine is stored locally - not in your project folder, but in the gems folder. You just need to override the gem files with your own desired behaviour :) And this works, because your project files take precedence over your gems / engines.

Comment: What's the error in ``app/views/spree/products/_image.html.erb``?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21209138/how-to-override-a-file-that-is-causing-trouble-in-ruby-on-rails-spree-commerce-a

Comment: This solved the op problem but isn't a proper solution, please consider the @rcsole 's answer below which I think it's far better.

Comment: @Bursos this is the way Rails engines work. the solution I suggested works pretty well because Spree uses partials as well so you can also just replace small parts of their views. mixing HTML and Ruby, as the other answer suggests, is not the best practice in my opinion, especially not if you've got big chunks of it (and I do get that Spree uses `deface`, but Spree is also a Rails engine).

Comment: @lipanski the answer solves the problem but it is [clearly](https://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/view.html) not the way recommended by the spree gem.

Answer (score 2):

First off, I think this question is duplicated in several other SO questions. I did deal with this yesterday though, so I figured I would give an answer.

You should look at the **deface** gem (what Spree uses to allow you to override views). Here's an example on how to **replace** the content of `<ul id="main-nav-bar" class="inline">`, assuming the file is `app/views/spree/shared/_nav_bar.html.erb`. Note that you have to find the file where the selector you're going to use actually is:

```
# app/overrides/my_override.rb
Deface::Override.new(virtual_path: "spree/shared/nav_bar",
                     name: "my_navbar",
                     replace: "ul#main-nav-bar") do
  <<-HTML
  <nav class='navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top'>
    <div class='container'>
      ...
    </div>
  </nav>
  HTML
end
```

If you need more help you might want to take a look at their [docs](https://github.com/spree/deface). What is definitely not a good idea is to copy and paste the content of a gem to override.