# How to override a file that is causing trouble in Ruby on Rails Spree Commerce App?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, overriding, spree

After having updated from Rails 3 to Rails 4 and installing the [Bootstrap gem for Spree](https://github.com/jdutil/spree_bootstrap/) I get an error in `app/views/spree/products/_image.html.erb`. The page looks as follows after I click on a image of a product on the main page:

```
 NameError in Spree::Products#show 

 Showing []/ruby/1.9.1/bundler
/gems/spree_bootstrap-a529d6bb6db0/app/views/spree/products/_image.html.erb where line 
#1 raised:

undefined local variable or method `image' for 
#<#<Class:0x000000070139c8>:0x000000068d7da8>

Extracted source (around line #1):

1
2
3
4

    <% if image %>
    <%= image_tag image.attachment.url(:product), :itemprop => "image" %>
    <% else %>
    <%= product_image(@product, :itemprop => "image") %>

Trace of template inclusion: []app/views/spree/products/show.html.erb

Rails.root: []/rails/releases/20140118194836
```

I know that [this can be fixed by changing the file that is ruining it to only contain `<%= product_image(@product, :itemprop => "image") %>`](https://github.com/jdutil/spree_bootstrap/issues/14). And I [learned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21208300/how-to-override-change-lay-out-of-ruby-on-rails-spree-app-after-installing-boots/21208877#21208877) that I need to override files if I want them to change.

So I want to change the code there so locally I added a file with the same path and name (`app/views/spree/products/_image.html.erb`) with the desired new code. Then I deployed it and when I ssh into the server I see the file. But on the website I still get the same error. Since trace of template inclusion said it came from `app/views/spree/products/show.html.erb` I also changed that file to it, but I still see the same code on the server.

How do I fix this?

Comment: The answer is in your link to the GitHub issue. So you can either remove the first ``image_tag image.attachment.url(:product)`` block entirely or you can replace it with ``<% if local_assigns[:image].present? && image %>``.

Comment: The question is mainly how do I replace the code? :) thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create [this file](https://github.com/jdutil/spree_bootstrap/blob/master/app/views/spree/products/_image.html.erb) in your project folder, then replace the contents with:

```
<%= product_image(@product, :itemprop => "image") %>
```

Or with this:

```
<% if local_assigns[:image].present? && image %>
  <%= image_tag image.attachment.url(:product), :itemprop => "image" %>
<% else %>
  <%= product_image(@product, :itemprop => "image") %>
<% end %>
```

And btw, I don't see any need to overwrite `app/views/spree/products/show.html.erb` if you're only doing it to get rid of the error. The error is within the `_image` partial, as stated in the GitHub issue.

Comment: That was exactly what I did but it did not (seem) to help. I looked again and realized that I did `mkdir products -> touch _image.html.erb` instead of `mkdir products -> cd products -> touch _image.html.erb`. Nice.  Well, this was the answer so have an upvote. :)